# Replace for loops in this MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is there any way I can avoid using loops in the following code?
I am doing a reduce summation, that is grouping a and sum all the values of same index from b.

```
a = [ 1 3 2 3 1 2]
b = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6]
for i = unique(a)
     c(i) = sum(b(ismember(a, i)))
 end
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are triying to do?

Comment: I am doing a reduce summation, that is grouping a and sum all the values of the same index from b.

Comment: You need to loop for a reduce sumation. Also, that code doesn't seem to be doing reduce sumation....

Comment: OK, if loop is unavoidable, advices on making the code more native to matlab users are also great!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, if you could list the output `c` you are looking to get, we may be able to help you better. You may be looking for `accumarray`

Comment: Reduce summations are fantastic in GPUs, but in MATLAB, just use `sum(b)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly* what [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is meant for:

```
>> accumarray(a.',b.')
ans =

   0.60000
   0.90000
   0.60000
```

*<sub>Actually, this is the *simplest* thing that `accumarray` does. It defaults to `@sum`, but you can specify your own function to tell it what to do with the accumulated indices.</sub>

Comment: In the event that the more general version of the problem doesn't have the entries of `a` being pure indices for `b`, you might also look into `findgroups` and `splitapply` (which are also way easier to deal with if you need to group over multiple variables).

Comment: @CKT Thanks! These are new functions that I haven't had a chance to play with yet. I'll have to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **very expensive** avoidance of the loops:

```
rsum = b*(bsxfun(@eq,a.',unique(a)));
```

The sums are given in the increasing order of `a`'s elements. Also, works for the case when `a` is not index in `b`.

Comment: nice `bsxfun` here.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thanks, I had great `bsxfun` teachers here on SO. :-)

Comment: :D Let me guess, Divakar?

Comment: @GameOfThrows Haha, you didn't need three guesses... :-)